# How to register global variable for my Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have started with Laravel a few days ago, and today I just installed the [`vespakoen/menu`](https://github.com/vespakoen/menu) that seems to be very nice, and probably will work for what I need it.

Currently I have installed Laravel 5.1 on my system.

The problem I currently have, is where to register my menus in order to be accessible by my application, on every view.

Should I create a service provider? Should I create a single class and included on bootstrap process? What is the correct way to perform this task?

*Note: The question is not how to install the `module`, but how can I have access to the `$menu` variable from any `view` from any `controller`.*

Comment: @halfer, hello, and thank for the corrections, but people don't know what is my skill set, so, the solution maybe it's obvious for some users and they think I ask bud qustions, and getting downvotes due to this situation.

Comment: I downvoted because you reverted my edit, though for now I've changed my mind, and retracted the vote. Just bear in mind that reverting edits looks like you're starting an edit war, which does not go down too well here.

Comment: xaxaxaxa. I am not in war with anyone :) Just I liked to make clear what is my skill set, and prevent downvotes in case my question is not so good. Anyway, do you have any answer to my problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you should reserve in **config/app.php** file. Then, you can add

```
In the Service Providers array : 'Menu\MenuServiceProvider',
In the aliases array : 'Menu' => 'Menu\Menu',
```

Finally, you need to run the following command;

```
 php artisan dump-autoload
```

I assume that you already added this package in **composer.json**

Sorry, I didn't clear your question that before you edited. I'm not sure that you cannot call $menu variable in your view or your controller. Based on my experience, I will make this with injection way.

In **routes.php**;

```
App::bind('MenuCreator',function($app) {
    return new yournamespace\YourMenuClass();
});
```

In **YourMenuClass.php**

Let's say I have a function call createMenu

```
 public function createMenu {
      //TODO create Menu and styling Menu
 }
```

If I want to call this injection method, I can access this way;

```
 $menuClass = App::make('MenuCreator');
 $menuClass->createMenu();
```

Please note that, you need to import **App**. And also you need to run

```
 php artisan dump-autoload
```

Hope this help. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Kelvin Kyaw thanks for you answer. The question is not how to register the module on Laravel, but how can I create a menu variable, that will contain the menu items, so later I will have access on the menu via the views. I already have register the module on Laravel. The excact question is in which Laravel file should I create a new menu, in order to have the menu available in any view.

Comment: You mean, you want to call your created menu in view file?

Comment: Currently I have create a Dashboard, and from within the dashboard I handle all my resources (users/roles/permissions/products/categories/ ect). For each of those entities, I have a seperate controller file. So, in order to display a menu for each of the controllers, I should register the menu in a place other than the controllers. ( I suppose :) )

Answer (score 1):

Recently, In my previous project I'm able to deal with same requirement using [View Composer](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers).

And I believe it's better approach to deal with while you working on such requirement for laravel5.

If you want example implementation, let me know.